# A link with a differentiating ccTLD

Tags: html, blogger, blogspot

I am using blogger. I am not an expert.
I'm trying to add an image on a post, with a link that differentiates according to the ccTLD you are on.

so for example, if you're on "example.blogspot **.ca**", the link attached to the image will be "example.blogspot **.ca**/p/blog-page_25.html"

And if you're on "example.blogspot **.nl**", the link attached to the image will be "example.blogspot **.nl**/p/blog-page_25.html"

And if you're on "example.blogspot **.com**", the link attached to the image will be "example.blogspot **.com**/p/blog-page_25.html"

Hopefully, you understand what I'm trying to say.

Can someone help me to do it?

Comment: I actually don't how to do it, so nothing. As I said, I'm not an expert.... but I know that the links of "header" and "page-list widget" are a differentiating links.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add hyperlink of your blog to any of your post, you don't have to worry about ccTLD. **This is because, blogspot automatically takes care this for you.**

According to Google:

> Country-specific domains is not a different blog address, but a domain redirect based on the country where you're currently located.([Source](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2402711?hl=en))

So use simple `.com` with your post/page url and anyone clicking on it will be redirected to appropriate ccTLD automatically.

You can even try this by yourself: Write your blog address with .com, it will load the page from the nearest server. In my case, if I hit **example.blogspot .com**, then it loads for me, **example.blogspot.in**.